# NEDB $and operator

Tags: javascript, nedb, justonedb

I am using nedb embedded database.
I have 6 below records in database,

> {"file":"LogFile4","time":"2018-05-30","ip":"20:12:36:169","process_id":" 9492","thread_id":"984","component_id":"Standalone","lock_level":1,"source_file":" /m_uac_helpers.cpp","lan_no":" 72","function_name":" uGetProcessIntegrityLevel()","description":" Running on medium integrity level","date":{"$$date":1533316439751},"_id":"04dcgjqvamb3Q2ZP"}
>
> {"file":"LogFile1","time":"2018-05-30","ip":"20:12:36:169","process_id":" 9492","thread_id":"984","component_id":"Standalone","lock_level":1,"source_file":" /m_uac_helpers.cpp","lan_no":" 72","function_name":" uGetProcessIntegrityLevel()","description":" Running on medium integrity level","date":{"$$date":1533316401978},"_id":"30REJoEkoDRz2Pa7"}
>
> {"file":"LogFile","time":"2018-05-30","ip":"20:12:36:169","process_id":" 9492","thread_id":"984","component_id":"Standalone","lock_level":1,"source_file":" /m_uac_helpers.cpp","lan_no":" 72","function_name":" uGetProcessIntegrityLevel()","description":" Running on medium integrity level","date":{"$$date":1534183887217},"_id":"5KUJtLyIoid55wNL"}
>
> {"file":"LogFile2","time":"2018-05-30","ip":"20:12:36:169","process_id":" 9492","thread_id":"984","component_id":"Standalone","lock_level":1,"source_file":" /m_uac_helpers.cpp","lan_no":" 72","function_name":" uGetProcessIntegrityLevel()","description":" Running on medium integrity level","date":{"$$date":1533316421021},"_id":"83jMpB2SB1hnpuXU"}
>
> {"file":"LogFile3","time":"2018-05-30","ip":"20:12:36:169","process_id":" 9492","thread_id":"984","component_id":"Standalone","lock_level":1,"source_file":" /m_uac_helpers.cpp","lan_no":" 72","function_name":" uGetProcessIntegrityLevel()","description":" Running on medium integrity level","date":{"$$date":1533316430692},"_id":"MJETZ6PtNxMXk817"}
>
> {"file":"LogFile","time":"2018-05-30","ip":"20:12:36:169","process_id":" 9493","thread_id":"984","component_id":"Standalone","lock_level":1,"source_file":" /m_uac_helpers.cpp","lan_no":" 72","function_name":" uGetProcessIntegrityLevel()","description":" Running on medium integrity level","date":{"$$date":1533316384810},"_id":"WUdpGQ8ec7WqwaJh"}

I do not want records which contain file = "LogFile" and process_id="9493" but i want those records which contains only one of those.

I am using below query,
'$and': [ { '$not': { process_id: "9493"} }, {file: "LogFile"} ] ,

But it also excludes records which has only process_id: "9493" or file: "LogFile".

How can I remove only those records with both fields present.

Thanks

Comment: Hi bahman parsamanesh, can you suggest any solution?

Comment: If you want someone to see your comment, put `@` before their username. But if he had any solution he would have posted an answer, not just fixed the question formatting.